# Folding a sequential stream in Java

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream, reduce, fold

I'm used to programming in Scala, but I have to write some Java, and I'm trying to perform the equivalent of the following Scala snippet:

```scala
trait Options[K, V] {
  def add(key: K , value: V): Options[K, V]
}

val options: Options[T, U] = ???
val elems: List[(T, U)] = ???
elems.foldLeft(options) {
  case (opts, (key, value)) => opts.add(key, value)
}
```

That is, I'm folding the elements on `elems` inside `options`, producing a new instance at each step.

I tried to use Java's [`Stream#reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```
interface Options<K, V> {
  Options<K, V> add(K key, V value);
}

Options<K, V> options = ???
Stream<Tuple2<K, V>> elems = ??? // This is Reactor's Tuple2
elems.reduce(options, (opts, opt) -> opts.add(opt), ???)
```

I don't know what the combiner should be, and I'm having trouble imagining what values its arguments will have. My understanding is that the `combiner` will be used to combine intermediate values produced in parallel in a parallel stream. I do not care at all about processing `elems` in parallel in my case. In other terms, I'm looking for a synchronous and sequential version of [`Flux#reduce`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#reduce-A-java.util.function.BiFunction-).

I have no control on the API of `Options`. `elems` does not need to be a `Stream`.

Comment: Hi Martin!
Do you need just to put all the Tuples from elems to Optoins with using add() method?

Comment: Your interface returns a raw type: `Options add(K key, V value)` It should be `Options<K, V> add(K key, V value)`

Comment: Hi! Yes. Note that `Options` is immutable: Each call to `add` will return a new instance of `Options` which will contain the newly added element. I could loop over the elements of `elems`, but I'm looking for a way to achieve this without using a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to write a combiner with the interface you've provided. The problem is that a combiner needs a way to combine two `Options` but there is no way to do that. The only thing anyone can do with an `Options` instance is add one pair to it. I can't get any information out of it. It presumably can't do anything very useful.

Perhaps this issue stems from the fact that Java does not have traits and neither are Java interfaces a suitable substitute for traits.

The idiomatic Java way to write this is just a bog-standard for-loop:

```
Options<String, String> options = /*whatever*/;
List<Pair<String, String>> elems = /*whatever*/;
for (Pair<String, String> pair : elems)
{
    options = options.add(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue());
}
```

If you can deal with the fact that you'll never been able to use a parallel stream, you can take advantage of the fact that a sequential stream will never actually use a combiner. As such, you can write a `Collector` which defines a combiner that will just throw an exception.

```
Options<String, String> foo = elems.stream()
    .collect(
        () -> options,
        (opt, pair) -> opt.add(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue()),
        (a, b) -> { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    );
```

If you really want to use `reduce`, you'll need to modify your interface to either expose some information about the key-value pairs it contains or to provide a means to add more than one key-value pair at once. For example:

```
interface Options<K, V>
{
    Options<K, V> add(K key, V value);
    Options<K, V> add(Options<K, V> otherOptions);
}

Options<String, String> options = /*whatever*/;
List<Pair<String, String>> elems = /*whatever*/;

Options<String, String> foo = elems.stream()
    .reduce(
        options,
        (opt, pair) -> opt.add(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue()),
        Options::add
    );
```

I doubt that's what you wanted to hear but Scala and Java are different languages. You shouldn't expect everything to have an exact parallel. If it did, there would be no reason for both languages to exist in the first place.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for looking into my question. I was wondering whether achieving what I want would be possible using the `Collectors`, but couldn't figure out. Scala and Java are indeed different; I expected however that an operation as common as the one I describe in my question would have a simple solution in Java. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Martin I realised that it is actually possible but it relies on the fact that a sequential stream will never make use of a Combiner. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Michael I remember that Stuart Marks once said here that currently there is no usage of the `combiner` for non-parallel streams (and he does not see some usage for it), but it might happen, you never know when someone finds some intriguing usage for it for non-parallel executions